# Handling IP address on Linaro OS

Tags: debian, networkmanager

I'm trying to handle the network settings on Linaro OS (ARM).

If I use the GUI applet then the system is using the NetworkManager way and
it compiles the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connection/net-name.nmconnection` setting file.
I need to change the network settings (basically switching from manual and DHCP or viceversa) from a local web page, so under the Apache+PHP control.
I can achieve it by modifying the file (complex) or by command line (which command(s)??).

Alternatively I can compile the `/etc/network/interfaces` file - the NetworkManager shoud ignore the settings defined in this file; maybe it is less complex but I'd like to set the 'ignore other obtained routes/addresses' flag, possible with the NetworkManager but I don't know in `interfaces` file.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to use the `nmtui` if I have a terminal console.
When I need to change from a web page/PHP I use the
command:

```
nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 2' setting.property value
```

Quite simple to integrate in a bash script and run from PHP side.